# How to implement a Kalman Filter

Tags: filtering

Below I use low level code to reproduce the example of a Kalman Filter on pages 16-20 found [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs4758/2012sp/materials/MI63slides.pdf). First I create the data.

```
meas={0.32,0.42,0.13,0.48,0.82,0.7,0.93,0.84,0.78,0.76,1.35,1.2,1.07,1.3,1.8,
1.3,1.77,2.0,2.1,1.77};
len=Length@meas;
measurement@0=truth@0=0;
Do[truth[i]=0.1*i;
   measurement[i]=Part[meas,i],
   {i,1,len,1}
];
```

Next I filter the data.

```
r=0.1;
q=0.00001;
H={{1,0},{0,0}};
A={{1,1},{0,1}};
X[0]={{0.0},{0}};
P[0]={{1,0},{0,1}};
Q=q*10^-9*{{1/3,0.5},{0.5,1}};
R=10^-7{{r,0},{0,r}};
KalmanGain[0]=P[0].Transpose[H].Inverse[H .P[0].Transpose[H]+R];
Do[
   (X[k]=A.X[k-1];
   P[k]=A.P[k-1].Transpose[A]+Q;
   KalmanGain[k]=P[k].Transpose[H].Inverse[H .P[k].Transpose[H]+R];
   X[k]=X[k]+KalmanGain[k].(measurement[k]-H.X[k]);
   P[k]=(IdentityMatrix[2]-KalmanGain[k].H).P[k]),
   {k,len}
];
```

Then I plot the results and get the same result as the plot at the above web-page.

```
measurementPlot=ListLinePlot[{#,measurement@#}&/@Range[0,len],
   Mesh->All,PlotStyle->{Thickness@0.001,Black},
   MeshStyle->{AbsolutePointSize@7,Black}
];
filteredPlot=ListLinePlot[{#,Part[X@#,1,1]}&/@Range[0,len],
   Mesh->All,PlotStyle->{Thickness@0.001,Magenta},
   MeshStyle->{AbsolutePointSize@7,Magenta}
 ];
 truePlot=ListLinePlot[{#,truth@#}&/@Range[0,len],Mesh->All,
 PlotStyle->{Thickness@0.001,Yellow},
 MeshStyle->{AbsolutePointSize@7,Yellow}
];
Show[measurementPlot,filteredPlot,truePlot,GridLinesStyle->Black,
AxesStyle->Black,Background->GrayLevel@0.8,
GridLines->{{},{0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0}},PlotRange->{0,2.25},
ImageSize->{550,400},AspectRatio->0.8]
```

[image]
How could I used [KalmanEstimator](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KalmanEstimator.html) or similar built-in functions to get 
the same result?

Comment: Have you looked at this [documentation article](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/ConstructAKalmanFilterForAStochasticSystem.html)?

Comment: @m_goldberg, I read that part of the documentation before. However, it's still very hard to see how that example can be modified to the application  above.